# Making a slideshow in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery, and I would like to know what can be improved of the code in this [slideshow](https://jsfiddle.net/coffqfwm/3/).

```
(function ($) {
let pointer = 0;

let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlide');
for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.left = 100 * i + "%";
    $('#dots').append('<span class="dot"></span>');
}

function changeSlide() {
    $('#slider').css('left', -100 * pointer + '%');
    changeDot();
    pointer++;
    if (pointer > (slides.length - 1)) pointer = 0;
    setTimeout(changeSlide, 3000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    changeSlide();
});

})(jQuery);
```

As can be observed in the code, I'm changing the *left* property of the `<div>` inside another `<div>` with `overflow: hidden` where the images are set to `position: absolute`.

Comment: So is the code in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coffqfwm/3/) your code? if so, please update your code sample so it is complete (e.g. to contain functions not defined, e.g. `changeDot()`); Otherwise, if it isn't your code, are you asking if you can make something similar? That statement "_I would like to know if I can do things like this_" is slightly vague....

Comment: I posted only a bit of code here, the rest is on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cache DOM lookups

When iterating over the elements with class name *mySlide* in the `for` loop, there is a look-up for the dots container (i.e. `$('#dots')`). Bearing in mind that the example only contains four slide elements, that could lead to excess DOM queries. It is good to store references like that and then utilize the reference:

```
const dotsContainer = $('#dots');

//later: (e.g. in for loop)
dotsContainer.append('<span class="dot"></span>');
```

#### Consistency

Why mix native JavaScript (e.g. getting the elements with class name *mySlide*: `document.getElementsByClassName('mySlide');`) and then use jQuery later on (e.g. getting elements with class name *dot*: `$('.dot')`?

That first block to loop over the elements with class name *mySlide* could be re-written in jQuery style:

```
const dotsContainer = $('#dots'); //cache the DOM lookup for later
const slides = $('.mySlide');//document.getElementsByClassName('mySlide');
slides.each(function(i, element) { //for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    $(element).css({left: 100 * i + "%"});//slides[i].style.left = 100 * i + "%";
    dotsContainer.append('<span class="dot"></span>');
});
```

#### Closure simplification

Some of the closures can be simplified - for instance:

> ```
> $('.dot').each(function () {
>   $(this).removeClass('is-active');
> });
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
$('.dot').removeClass('is-active');
```

And the same is true for the DOM-ready callback:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     changeSlide();
> });
> ```

Can be simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(changeSlide);
```

#### jQuery DOM-ready syntax:

As of jQuery 3.0, only `$(handler)` is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.<sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup>

So that ready callback registration can be simplified to:

```
$(changeSlide);
```

Many of these tips are explained in more detail in [this article from a couple years avo](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). It does start off by making one question how much jquery is really needed these days- a valid question. For more on that topic, check out [you might not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```js
(function ($) {

  let pointer = 0;
  //store instead of looking up each time
    const dotsContainer = $('#dots');
  let slides = $('.mySlide');//document.getElementsByClassName('mySlide');
  slides.each(function(i, element) { //for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    $(element).css({left: 100 * i + "%"});//slides[i].style.left = 100 * i + "%";
    dotsContainer.append('<span class="dot"></span>');
  });

  $('.dot').each(function (i) {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
      $('#slider').css('left', -100 * i + '%');
      pointer = i;
      changeDot();
    });
  });

  function changeDot() {
    $('.dot').removeClass('is-active');
    $('.dot').eq(pointer).addClass('is-active');
  }

  function changeSlide() {
    $('#slider').css('left', -100 * pointer + '%');
    changeDot();
    pointer++;
    if (pointer > (slides.length - 1)) pointer = 0;
    setTimeout(changeSlide, 3000);
  }

  $(changeSlide);

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: #28262b;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif-sans;
}

#slider-wrap {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #39373a;
  border: 1px solid #17151c;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider {
  height: 500px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.mySlide {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

#dots {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
.dot {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #616161;
}

.is-active {
  background: white;
}
.dot.is-active:hover {
  background: pink;
  border-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="slider-wrap">
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="mySlide">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300'/>
        </div>
        <span class="description">test1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlide">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/301/300'/>
        </div>
        <span class="description">test2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="mySlide">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/302/300'/>
        </div>
        <span class="description">test3</span>
      </div>
       <div class="mySlide">
        <div class="photo">
          <img src='https://www.fillmurray.com/303/300'/>
        </div>
        <span class="description">test4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dots"></div>
</body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://api.jquery.com/ready/</sub>

Comment: thank you so much for this long hardly helpful comment! wow

Comment: You're welcome, but what do you mean by *hardly*?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ [English by foreigners](https://www.boredpanda.com/translation-fails/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic)